# How can I map a server group to a common root?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, application-server

I would like to run a JBoss 7.1.1.Final in domain mode. The server groups should be accessible separately, under a common root URL:

```
 myserver/server-group-1/Application1

 myserver/server-group-2/Application1
```

I have no idea how and where to configure it.

I have not found anything on the topic in the "JBoss AS 7 Configuration, Deployment and Administration" book and web searches were not helpful either.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by "server groups should be accessible separately, under a common root URL". Server groups are not applications. In domain modes apps are deployed to a server group which comprises of 1 or more servers (jboss instances).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to front end your app servers with a webserver like Apache/Tomcat. The domain mode servers will communicate to each other to provide fail safety. Some useful information is available at the link:

https://community.jboss.org/message/797872?_sscc=t